# Multiple groups instead of one

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to match URLs, and so far it's working great – except I'm getting more than one group. I would like to just get one group if I can. My goal is to get the address all the way up to a single (forward) slash.

For example, given this URL

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#BABGDJFH
```

the output would be:

```
http://docs.oracle.com
```

Also on another note, there are times that the beginning `http` or `https` isn't there; but it is optional, and I don't need it anyways.

**Current Regex I'm Using**

```
 ^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)([a-z\]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)
```

The first group is optional, which means the URL can begin with `http` or `https` or neither of them. The rest is for the domain name itself. When I run the above regex, I get back what I need but in more groups than just one; and I would like to get just one group. If there's `http` or `https` at the beginning, it is one group, and then the site address is another group.

**For Testing Purposes**

```
  Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)([a-z\]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)")
  Dim m As Match = regex.Match(txtURL.Text.Trim)
  Dim lst As New List(Of String)

  Do While m.Success
      For i = 1 To 2
          Dim g As Group = m.Groups(i)
          lst.Add(g.ToString)
      Next
      Exit Do
  Loop

  ' Jump through hoops to account for one or two groups.
  If lst.Count = 1 Then
      txtConvertedURL.Text = (lst(0))
  ElseIf lst.Count = 2 Then
      txtConvertedURL.Text = (lst(0) & lst(1))
  End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an outer grouping to achieve this:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)([a-z]{2,6}))([\/\w \.-]*)")
'                                ^                                       ^
Dim m As Match = regex.Match(txtURL.Text.Trim)
Dim lst As New List(Of String)

Do While m.Success
    For i = 1 To 2
        Dim g As Group = m.Groups(i)
        lst.Add(g.ToString)
    Next
    Exit Do
Loop

If lst.Count > 1 Then
    txtConvertedURL.Text = (lst(0))
End If
```

**Edit:**

@Jasen and I simul-answered: what he said regarding there still being multiple groups but the first of them being the whole match you want.

*Also*, the `ArgumentException` that I pointed out in my comment on Jasen's answer ended up coming down to the backslash within `[a-z\]` in the question's original pattern (once additional parens – though balanced – were introduced).  Tying back to the original language of the question ("...all the way up to a single backslash."), the `\` within `[a-z\]` does not make (obvious) sense – certainly not in relation to the sample input URL in the question.

A single *forward* slash rather than a backslash would indicate the end of the host/domain in the URL of course; and `\/` in `([\/\w \.-]*)` that follows accounts for that: the backslash within `[a-z\]` in the original pattern then seems erroneous: I have dropped it in my updated answer that produces the desired output for the sample input provided.

Comment: I tested this as well and it doesn't work, it's giving me the whole URL.

Comment: @Codexer: See my latest edit, and let me know whether this resolves the issue.  From my local tests, it seems to.

Comment: @JOe3gan that works well, thank you. I didn't think about wrapping it in an outer group. It's late and I'm tired. Thanks again!

Comment: @Codexer: Glad to hear it.  Being light on sleep sometimes makes the obvious not so obvious - as I unfortunately know all too well. :)  BTW, if I overstepped a bit by taking "backslash" in your question's original wording to mean "(forward) slash", tweak your question with a follow-on edit of course.  The code in my answer works for the sample input you provided either way (i.e. with both versions of the regex I showed that simply differ in their "backslashness").

Comment: The code works great. Ive tested it on about 780 addresses so far and its working great with no issues. And yes its forward.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

put parentheses around the groups:

```
^((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)([a-z\]{2,6}))([\/\w \.-]*)
```

you'll still get multiple groups, but the first group will be protocol and domain

by the way, that regex stopped working this year. TLDs are no longer limited to 6 characters.
please complain at whoever gave it to you.

lose the '6' and it'll work better

```
^((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)([a-z\]{2,}))([\/\w \.-]*)
```

Comment: I think you are missing the second closing paren that you intended - i.e. another `)` at the end.  As it stands, the pattern you've shown yields *ArgumentException: parsing "^((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)([a-z\]{2,6}))([\/\w \.-]\*)" - Not enough )'s.*.  As I noted in the edit to my answer, though, I think we really meant the same thing.

Comment: @J0e3gan  No, the second paren is after the domain part, as requested.

Comment: I tested this it's not working. It's giving me the whole URL still, I want from the beginning up to the first "/".

Comment: try the second group - I'm not familiar with Microsoft's regex, but Posix puts thre whole match in slot number 0 and th first group in number 1